# How can I delete a word from a String in Visual C#

Tags: c#

How can I delete a word from a String in Visual C#

```
string message = "Hi, Your Password is: 123456. Thanks"
```

How can I delete ". Thanks"

I just need to get 123456.

Comment: Do you want to delete . Thanks   Or do you want to delete everything except 123456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace it with  `""`:

```
string.Replace("Thanks","")
```

or,
(this is not ideal in your case, but in case you want to learn more)

```
string.Split("Thanks")[0] ///this splits the string depending on the given value, the index `0` is to get everything before the point you splitted
```

Or to get only `123456`, you can go with the split method as-well :

```
string.Split(" ")[4]

//or

string newstring = string1.split(":")[1]
string result = newstring.Replace(" ","") 
 // or 
 string result = new.splti(" ")[1]
```

Or you can get the numbers only from the string :

```
 string mystring =new String(mainstring.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())
```

Or regex is always your best friend :

```
 string finalstring = Regex.Match(mainstring, @"\d+").Value;
```

This wil return the string it finds first with numbers in it :)

Comment: Should be `string.Split("Thanks")[0]`.

Comment: string newmessage = "Hi, Your Password is: 123456" How to get last character.

Comment: Try my last solution to get only `123456`

Comment: Please re-read my answer and mark it as an answer if it helped

Comment: 1. You can't use `new` as variable name. 2. Don't beg for accepts. 3. You can't access an index with `(1)`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann , please re-read my answer and sorry for asking to accept :( .....

Comment: string.Split(" ")[4] how to use last word. string.Split()[0] .Last ?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann,what edit are you talking about ?

Comment: @GrandMasterTurks , what ??

Comment: @GrandMasterTurks , i don't understand, what is ur expected result ?

Comment: string newmessage = "Hi, Your Password is: 123456" how to get last word ? 123456

Comment: Follow my third solution that starts with `string newstring =`

Comment: or if it always numbers,you can use my last solution too :)

Comment: Thanks for help :) it is works.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string.Replace("Thanks","");
```

this will replace all Thanks with "". you can also pass a complete string.

example

```
"this is a test string".Replace("test string","text line");
```

so the result will be "this is a text line"

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he wants only `123456` ....

Comment: @zackraiyan The OP clearly states that he wants to delete `. Thanks`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is helpful in this type of scenario

```
regex = new Regex("^\d+$");
```

^ will mark the beginning of the string, the $ will mark the end of the string, and the + will match one or more of what precedes it(ie. number) and  \d is used to get number between[0-9].

Answer (score 0):

If password is only number you can this

```
string message = "Hi, Your Password is: 123456. Thanks";

string password = string.Empty;

for (int i=0; i< message.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(message[i]))
        password += message[i];
}
```

http://rextester.com/HHIIP91760